# Camel Json Validation throws NoJsonBodyValidationException

Tags: rest, validation, apache-camel, openapi, spring-camel

I'm trying to perform Header validation for incoming GET request. I referred the [Camel JSON schema validator component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-json-validator/src/main/docs/json-validator-component.adoc) and followed below steps to implement in my project i.e.

- Adding camel-json-validator-starter dependency in build.gradle
- Adding Employee.json (YAML converted to JSON) in Resource folder of my Spring boot project. Here initially I had Open API 3.0 yaml specification file and I converted the same to json
- Invoking validation with below code

  ```
  rest(/employee).id("get-employee")
      .produces(JSON_MEDIA_TYPE)
      .get()
      .description("The employee API")
      .outType(EmployeeResponse.class)
      .responseMessage()
        .code(HttpStatus.OK.toString())
        .message("Get Employee")
      .endResponseMessage()
      .route()
      .to("json-validator:openapi.json")
      .to("bean:employeeService?method=getEmployee()");
  ```

Running the project throws a `org.apache.camel.component.jsonvalidator.NoJsonBodyValidationException`, I'm using GET request but why is it expecting Request body, I just wanted to validate the Headers and request param from the incoming request. I'm not sure if my approach is right and what I'm missing.

Comment: Just a quick question are you using the JSON version of an OpenAPI specification to validate the message? If so it wont work. The JSON validator is not compatible with OpenAPI specification. You will need to convert the OpenAPI schema to the valid JSON Schema. Yes they are different see here https://json-schema.org/. You cannot use OpenAPI here. The headers etc are available in OpenAPI but JSON schema only validates JSON object. HTTP Headers do not fall into JSON objects.

Comment: To convert from open API 3.0 to json schema all I did was, loading original yaml file into swagger editor and then converting to json schema by "File -> convert and save as JSON". The generated json schema has header validation as well. Refer below extract of header definition from JSON Schema.                                                        
     `"RequestId": {
        "in": "header",
        "name": "x-et-request-id",
        "description": "Unique ID ",
        "schema": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 36
        },
        "required": true
      },`

Comment: @Namphibian All I wanted to achieve is validating headers against yaml/json schema for incoming request for GET method, and validating headers + request payload against yaml/json schema for POST method call. This I was trying to achieve using camel REST DSL but it's not straight forward though.

Comment: When you save the file as JSON you are just creating a OpenAPI specification in JSON format. This is still not JSON schema. It's very close but there are differences. What you are trying to do is not possible with the set of technologies. OpenAPI in json  format is not json schema they are completely different. It might work a bit as they are similar but json schema does not have operation such as get and post it is all about schema.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem last year when adopting OpenAPI and came to the conclusion that it was too much work. I could not get FULL validation from the JSON validator using OpenAPI because there was some differences between the way OpenAPI declares schema definitions and the full JSON schema definitions.

Looking a the documentation of the JSON validation component you find this:

The JSON Schema Validator component performs bean validation of the message body against JSON Schemas v4 draft using the NetworkNT JSON Schema library (https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator). This is a full stand alone JSON Schema and if you read the github pages you find this.

**OpenAPI Support**

***The OpenAPI 3.0 specification is using JSON schema to validate the request/response, but there are some differences***. With a configuration file, you can enable the library to work with OpenAPI 3.0 validation.

OpenAPI schema appears to be a subset of the real JSON Schema.

Before I show you a more detailed example. Look at the example given in the camel documentation here: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/json-validator-component.html. Compare that json schema file with the openAPI schema definitions and you will see they are not the same.

A useful tool here is  https://jsonschema.net you can paste your json example here and infer a schema. I use this tool and the OpenAPI Pet Store example in the example below,

OpenAPI Petstore Pet Object Example:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "category": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string"
  },
  "name": "doggie",
  "photoUrls": [
    "string"
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "status": "available"
}
```

The openAPI specification saved in JSON produces this definition:

```
  "Pet": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "photoUrls"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int64"
        },
        "category": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Category"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "example": "doggie"
        },
        "photoUrls": {
          "type": "array",
          "xml": {
            "name": "photoUrl",
            "wrapped": true
          },
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "array",
          "xml": {
            "name": "tag",
            "wrapped": true
          },
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Tag"
          }
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "pet status in the store",
          "enum": [
            "available",
            "pending",
            "sold"
          ]
        }
      },
      "xml": {
        "name": "Pet"
      }
    }
```

When I convert this to proper JSON schema syntax the JSON Schema looks like this:

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "required": [
    "id",
    "category",
    "name",
    "photoUrls",
    "tags",
    "status"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "$id": "#/properties/id",
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "The Id Schema",
      "default": 0,
      "examples": [
        0
      ]
    },
    "category": {
      "$id": "#/properties/category",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Category Schema",
      "required": [
        "id",
        "name"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "$id": "#/properties/category/properties/id",
          "type": "integer",
          "title": "The Id Schema",
          "default": 0,
          "examples": [
            0
          ]
        },
        "name": {
          "$id": "#/properties/category/properties/name",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Name Schema",
          "default": "",
          "examples": [
            "string"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        }
      }
    },
    "name": {
      "$id": "#/properties/name",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Name Schema",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "doggie"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "photoUrls": {
      "$id": "#/properties/photoUrls",
      "type": "array",
      "title": "The Photourls Schema",
      "items": {
        "$id": "#/properties/photoUrls/items",
        "type": "string",
        "title": "The Items Schema",
        "default": "",
        "examples": [
          "string"
        ],
        "pattern": "^(.*)$"
      }
    },
    "tags": {
      "$id": "#/properties/tags",
      "type": "array",
      "title": "The Tags Schema",
      "items": {
        "$id": "#/properties/tags/items",
        "type": "object",
        "title": "The Items Schema",
        "required": [
          "id",
          "name"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "$id": "#/properties/tags/items/properties/id",
            "type": "integer",
            "title": "The Id Schema",
            "default": 0,
            "examples": [
              0
            ]
          },
          "name": {
            "$id": "#/properties/tags/items/properties/name",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The Name Schema",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "string"
            ],
            "pattern": "^(.*)$"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "status": {
      "$id": "#/properties/status",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Status Schema",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "available"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    }
  }
}
```

There is some differences between OpenAPI's schema definition and JSON Schema definition.

Answer (score 1):

failOnNullBody (producer) - Whether to fail if no body exists.

Default is true

Try setting the option in your call:

```
.to("json-validator:openapi.json?failOnNullBody=false")
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for the response, I tried adding `.to("json-validator:openapi.json?failOnNullBody=false")` but still the issue exists i.e still throws the message _org.apache.camel.component.jsonvalidator.NoJsonBodyValidationException: No JSON body could be found on the input message. Exchange[ID-RVCRB439-1570421215006-0-1]_

Comment: There is another query parameter which may be relevant to you:
headerName (producer) - To validate against a header instead of the message body.

Comment: @MarkMcKeever JSON schema only validates JSON objects. See my comment on his question but I suspect he is using OpenAPI to try and validate a request. JSON Schema is very different from OpenAPI.

Comment: @MarkMcKeever thanks, it works for me now i.e. I can skip request payload validation with `.to("json-validator:openapi.json?headerName=header1")`

Comment: @MarkMcKeever what if I have multiple headers header1, header2, header3, I can't pass array/List of String? the documentation for JsonValidatorEndpoint accepts only String right. How do I pass all the headers for validation at once?

Comment: @Namphibian I followed Marks steps and was able to do header validation, however the headers are not validated against the header definition in openapi.json schema. As specifying `.to("json-validator:openapi.json?headerName=header1")` will only validate if the request has header by name header1 which is not null/blank, but other validation like length and datatype as specified in schema are not considered.

Comment: @Nicolas - I believe you use syntax as follows:
?name=value&name=value so for your example .to("json-validator:openapi.json?headerName=header1&headerName=header2&headerName=header3"